# Dynamicly adding JPanels to a JFrame

Tags: java, user-interface, dynamic, jpanel

This is my first question inhere, so please bear with me :)
Im working on a dynamic part of a GUI, and for some reason its teasing me.
The class is opened in a new window after login.
What I want, is for a new JPanel to be built and added to 'container' every time the "add player" button is clicked. It is supposed to put them below eachother, yet all it does is to add one button on the first click, and then the rest of the clicks afterwards does nothing.

Any help is appreciated :)

```
package Gui;

import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
//import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class TeamManagerGUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
//  private JLabel pNameLabel = new JLabel("Player Name: "),
//                  pSchoolLabel = new JLabel("School: ");
//  private JTextField pNameField = new JTextField(),
//                      pSchoolField = new JTextField();
    private JButton addButton = new JButton("Add Player"),
                    removeButton = new JButton("Remove player");
    private JPanel container = new JPanel(),
                    playerContainer = new JPanel();


    int frameCounter = 1;

    public TeamManagerGUI()
    {
        super("Team Manager User Interface");
        setSize(1200,800);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        container.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        playerContainer.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(3,3,3,3);
        addButton.addActionListener(this);
        container.add(addButton,gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(3,3,3,3);
        container.add(removeButton,gbc);

        this.add(container);
    }

    public void playerFrame()
    {
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        playerFrameArr.add(new JPanel());

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        playerContainer.add(new JButton("LABEL"),gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        playerContainer.add(new JButton("BUTTON"),gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = frameCounter+1;
        container.add(playerContainer,gbc);

        System.out.println(frameCounter);

        frameCounter++;
    }

    public void addPlayerRow()
    {
        playerFrame();
        container.revalidate();
        container.repaint();
    }

    public void removePlayerRow()
    {
        //Not yet implemented
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
    {
        if(ae.getSource() == addButton)
        {
            addPlayerRow();
        }
        if(ae.getSource() == removeButton)
        {
            //Not yet implemented
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding the `playerContainer` again and again. I think you should actually use the newly created `JPanel`. This one should be populated and added to the main container.

Adding a single panel multiple times will not render properly as this screws up the layout. I think you need to keep a reference to the new `JPanel` and fill this one with your layout and the buttons.

I am thinking something like this:

```
public void playerFrame()
{
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

    JPanel newPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    playerFrameArr.add(newPanel);

    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    newPanel.add(new JButton("LABEL"), gbc);

    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    newPanel.add(new JButton("BUTTON"), gbc);

    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = frameCounter + 1;
    container.add(newPanel, gbc);

    System.out.println(frameCounter);

    frameCounter++;
}
```

Comment: Now that they add fine, how can i remove them one at a time from the bottom? They dont have any real names, or am I missing something?

Comment: Well you got your `playerFrameArr` list don't you? You could retrieve the last entry from this list and remove this Panel from your container. Should work fine. You may also want to use the size of this list as the frame counter. That may come in handy if you want to add and remove those entries on a constant base.